# Reverse Engineer Access DB

Tags: database, database-design, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I was wondering if anyone knew how to reverse engineer an Access Database.  I would like to be able to generate the SQL code that is used to create the database tables and to insert all the records in the table.  In other words, I would like to create whats is similar to a MySQL dump file.

Any ideas would be great

thanks
jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing built into Access that will generate the DDL for your tables.

There are many third party tools however (ERWin, ERStudio, Visio, etc) that can generate the DDL for you.

I don't know anything that will generate the Insert scripts for you. Access does however have plenty of export/import options if you just want to create a copy of your data and then use that as an import source.

It should be pointed out that there's nothing stopping you from writing some VBA code to loop through the TableDefs and creating the DDL and insert scripts yourself.

Comment: Yeah, nothing stopping me but time :-)  Thanks.  I think Ill just recreate the tables in mySQL and do a dump, if no one else has any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm it didn't occur to me until your comment, but if what you described works for you, you might want to simply export the Access tables (via Export -> ODBC) to a DB that has better built-in tools and do the dump there.

Comment: I think you mean DDL not DLL.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach that may work, is to upsize your tables to SQL server, and then have SQL server generate scripts for you.

Unfortunately the resulting scripts would probably be only compatible with SQL server. So then you would have to run them on SQL server and then pull the data in tables down to access.

Access does support DDL, but unfortunately it does not have any tools are facilities built in to generate the scripts.